# Reinstalling backed-up Ubuntu image after installing windows?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

After intalling Ubuntu, it occurs to me that I should have installed Windows first, as I plan to dualboot. If I make a system image of my current Ubuntu installation (saving all my settings), can I then reinstall that in another partition and dualboot with Windows, or will I require a fresh reinstall from my liveCD?

I'm not particularly knowledgeable of Linux systems or dualbooting.

Comment: The question is not clear: Are you asking how to install a customized Ubuntu image (hard), or how to simply restore backed-up files (easy)?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing what you want is to:

- Take a full file backup (Documents, Videos, Music, ...)
- Install Windows, wiping everything
- "Try Ubuntu" and resize Windows partitions to make space for Ubuntu if your Windows installation disk does not allow not to use only part of your PC
- reboot into Windows (to ensure resizing was effective)
- shut down completely
- Install Ubuntu.
- restore your Ubuntu files

#### Why?

- You *can* take an image back up and restore it, but you also have to:

  - copy UEFI files
  - reinstall grub

*and those are hard to do*

Comment: Annoying, but thank you anyway. I may have to simply bite the bullet and manually re-configure all my settings in ubuntu post-installation.

Comment: @CrazyOatmeal if you backup and restore the `~/.config` directory too, all your configs should be restored as well

Answer (score 0):

Annoying, but thank you anyway. I may have to simply bite the bullet and manually re-configure all my settings in ubuntu post-installation.